# How can I wait for SU access after request?

Tags: android, su

My app requests SU access something like this:

```
Process p = null;
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

That prompts the user to allow or deny the access, but my app continues to execute the next line of code while the choice is displayed on the screen. How can I make the app wait until the user makes a choice at the prompt?

Comment: Yeah why? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Just to this, I think it will work:

```
Process p = Runtime.exec("foo");
int exitCode = p.waitFor();
```

it will wait for your process to end, and you'll also get the exit code.

Comment: Thanks but this makes the app hang because even after the user chooses to allow or deny SU access, the app just sits there waiting.

Comment: Yes. This is a very simple app so it should run on a single thread.

Comment: You will have to run this on a background thread, I don't think there are other possibilities!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @jdourlens ans you can try this add this code before your actual "su" call.

```
try
{   
    Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c ls");
    int exitCode = p2.waitFor();
}
catch(Exception e2)
{//do something}
```

So if the user selects "Always allow" option, things will work out.
I was also trying to read code Chainfires's library as well his website: https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser/blob/master/libsuperuser/src/eu/chainfire/libsuperuser/Shell.java

What I could figure out was to do a Blocking I/O call while the user grants super user access. A good way is to write a temp file, or do some random commands.
This is what I tried to do. Call ls with su, which will grants that process su access and then your next su call will have the appropriate access.